# insert into trigger on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, t-sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I am new to MySQL. I have two tables posts and notification. I am trying to create a trigger for every new row added in posts, I would to add that new row to notification_id.
its working properly on mysql but in phpmyadmin trigger won't execute , it gives an error

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '' at line 11

Here how my tables look like:

posts table

```
create table posts
(
id int,
 topic_id tinyint,
post_creator int,
post_date datetime,
post_content text
);
```

notification table

```
create table notification
(
    not_id int ,
    top_id tinyint,
    p_creator int,
    p_date datetime,
    p_content text
);
```

notification_id trigger

```
delimiter $$;
    create trigger notification_id before Insert on posts
    for each row 
    begin
        declare id int;
        declare topic_id int;
        declare post_creator int;
        declare post_date datetime;
        declare post_content text;
    
        insert into notification(not_id,top_id,p_creator,p_date,p_content) values(new.id,new.topic_id,new.post_creator,new.post_date,new.post_content);
    end$$;
```

Comment: So to be clear, you've already got the trigger created, and when you do an INSERT from MySQL it works correctly, but doing the same INSERT from phpMyAdmin fails with the error message? Are you inserting via the "Insert" tab or by typing in the SQL directly?

Answer (score 0):

1. create the tables first normally
2. Change the default delimiter in phpmyadmin interface [it is just under the textbox where you enter your query]
3. Run the create trigger script separately, without the lines of changing delimiter 
   So, your trigger's code should not have `delimiter $$;`